# How to make terrain under curve Geometry nodes

Tags: mesh, node-editor, objects, geometry-nodes, geometry

So I am just playing around with geometry nodes and looking for a clever way to generate meshes under the curve to form a terrain.
I want to be able to play around with the curve itself to make different procedural tracks.

What I have now is a working track (can probably be improved but I am fine with it for now)
[image]
[image]

My thoughts on how I would be able to generate a terrain:

1. Get the Z position of the curve (don't know how to get that Z position) for different points of that curve and make terrain under it by instancing an object/terrain.
   But I feel like this is the wrong way to go about it because you can't control the meshes you generate for the terrain by just instancing an object.
2. Or take a plane and subdivide it --> take the middle part of the plane and get it to the same height at the track, flatten the top so it doesn't interact with the track. And make the ends reach the 0 value of the height

Anyone has any clever ideas?

Edit:
What I want it to look like is like a small hill with the tracks on the highest point and a slope going downwards on both sides. Where the track is flat the surface matches, where the track goes up, the ground moves up like a hill.
[image]

Comment: can you pls add an image how it should look like? what is the end result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to make something generic to create an environment around something moving over the track and that can have elevation/ move with the tracks without having to model the terrain and shrinkwrapping the track on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is somenthing like this that your are aiming for?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is close to what I want to achieve yes. Bezier segment node will help me, ty.

Comment: @Struggling_Coder, please upvote Luiz Antonio's answer if you find it useful.